# Another measure of correlation between binary variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

There are several [measures of association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#Measures_of_association) (or contingency or correlation) between two binary variables $p$ and $q$, among others

- Pearson's [phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) 
  [image]
- [Cramér's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)

I wonder how the following number $\kappa$ relates to known measures, if it is statistically interesting, and under which name it is (possibly) discussed:

$$\kappa = 1 - \frac{2}{N}|p \triangle q|$$

with $|p \triangle q|$ the number of samples having property $p$ or property $q$ but not both (exclusive OR, symmetric difference), $N$ the total number of samples. Like the phi coefficient, $\kappa = ± 1$ indicates perfect agreement or disagreement, and $\kappa = 0$ indicates no relationship

Answer (score 0):

From the MSE companion site [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256556/whats-the-name-of-this-correlation-association-measure-between-binary-variables) I learned that this measure is called **Hamann similarity**. Thanks to user ttnphns.